# How to post a select class to a php mail script in place of the value?

Tags: php, forms, class, select

I am looking to post the class name or text from a select option, but not the value.

The value is used to pull through a price used elsewhere on the page, but I need to include the class or text from the select in an email.

form

```
    <form method="post" id="my-form" action="emailscript.php" form enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <select name="signMaterial" id="signMaterial" class="signMaterial" onchange="updateSignMaterial(); updateSignMaterialClass();">

    <option value="111" class="Black-Riven-Slate" >Slate - Italian Black (Riven)</option>
    <option value="222" class="Black-Honed-Slate" >Slate - Italian Black (Honed)</option>
        <option value="333" class="Black-Polished-Granite" >Granite - Black Polished</option>
        <option value="444" class="Green-Honed-Slate" >Green Hones Slate</option>
    </select>
```

emailscript

```
    $signMaterial = $_POST['signMaterial'];

    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Sign Material:</strong></td><td>".$signMaterial."</td></tr>";
```

Does anyone know if this is possible, i've tried data-class to no avail

```
    $signMaterialClass = $_POST['signMaterial']['data-class'];
```

Comment: `I need to include the class or text from the select in an email.`...I'd expect the text came from your database originally, didn't it? Normally people keep lists of possible dropdown options as reference data in their DB so it's easy to change them, and also so it's easy to re-use the descriptions associated with the actual values in other situations (such as emails!). So that should really be the approach...get the submitted ID, retrieve the matching description from the DB, and use that in the email text. a HTML form won't ever submit anything except the selected value of the input.

Comment: Do you have any control over the HTML at all?  If the value you want to post to the server is this text string and not the numbers, why not use this text string as the *value* for the options?  This sounds like a bit of an XY Problem, some other mistake led you here.

Answer (score -1):

You can't access HTML class on PHP side. Result of form submission is HTTP request which only will contain form values.
You can have hidden HTML input, in which you can insert option's class name on select.

Note that my JS skill are outdated and probably there's better way to do this.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var theSelect = document.getElementById("theSelect");
  var theClassOfSelect = document.getElementById("theClassOfSelect");
  theSelect.addEventListener('change', function handleChange(event) {
    theClassOfSelect.value = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].className;
  });
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <select name="theSelect" id="theSelect">
    <option value="111" class="classnameone">Example Option #1</option>
    <option value="222" class="classnametwo">Example Option #2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="theClassOfSelect" id="theClassOfSelect" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is certainly one option. The hidden field would need to be pre-populated with the text of the initially-selected option too, though (in case the user never changes the selection).